# Local database on windows phone 8

Tags: database, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-express, windows

I am a beginner at using windows phone SDK and I am trying to find the best method to create a local database to store app data on a windows phone 8 device. The data is to be stored from one page (not the main page) and retrieved and displayed from another page.

I have tried to use linq to sql and sqlite but as I am a beginner I do not know much about either method.

Can anyone recommend a good tutorial or a method which I can use?

PS: I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for you to create the database

```
public class dbDataContext : DataContext

{
    // Pass the connection string to the base class.

    public dbDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }

    // Specify a single table for the idea items.
    public Table<className> cn;

}
```

className is where all your Member variables will be stored with get set method.

then create the database as follows in the file (*.cs) where you want to create the database

```
private IdeaDataContext yourDb;    
yourDb = new dbDataContext("Data Source=isostore:/anyname.sdf");
```

your database is created

Comment: Thank you both!
Now if I want to read a value from a specific column of the database how can I do it?

Comment: Using linq. e.g.: var result = from value in someTable where value.id==12 select value;

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397933.aspx